# How to improve SQL performance for this case?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I issue following SQL:

```
Select * from myTable 
where myID  =123 
  and myDate >= (case when isnull(null,'')='' then myDate else null end)
```

Performance is pretty bad.

If I modify it like this:

```
Select * from myTable 
where myID  =123 
  and myDate >= myDate
```

the performance is much better.

My real SQL could be something like:

```
Select * from myTable 
where myID  =123 
  and myDate >= (case when isnull(@myDate,'')='' then myDate else null end)
```

`myDate` is `Datetime` column.

How to improve performance for this case?

Comment: What are the indexes on myTable?

Comment: `the performance is much better.` That is because you have a dud clause `mydate >= mydate` which is 100% always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If T-SQL then:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = NULL
IF @myDate IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable  
   WHERE myID  = 123    
   AND myDate >= @myDate
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable  
   WHERE myID  = 123    
   AND myDate >= ''
END
```

ELSE Param'd SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myTable  
 WHERE myID  = 123    
   AND (@myDate IS NULL OR myDate >= @myDate)
```

EDIT: Added NOT to the IF condition.

Comment: 1. In the first query the IF condition should probably be: `IF @myDate IS NOT NULL`. 2. Why the second query cannot be used with T-SQL as well?

Comment: @Andriy: Corrected the IF condition :) Thx. Regarding the second query, it does work in T-SQL too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works if myDate is not nullable.

And please make sure myDate and @myDate have the same datatypes

```
Select * from myTable 
where myID  =123 
  and myDate >= isnull(@myDate, myDate)
```

Beware of COALESCE: it can be demonstratably slower then ISNULL because of how it handles datatypes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select * from myTable where myID =123 and (@myDate IS NULL OR myDate IS NULL)
```

If that is not good enough for you, add a index on the `myDate` column

Answer (score 0):

First good news is you will like coalesce:

```
Select * from myTable 
 where myID =123 
   and COALESCE(myDate,'') >= @myDate
```

If myDate is a character, as it appears to be, then get rid of those nulls and replace with empty strings.

...and I assume you have a compound index on (myId,myDate)